# Question, problems around dialog based task flow

Tags: navigation, dialog, task-flow

I rarely see an app designed in a way where the app asks you questions about what you want, like a dialogue. Instead, the app leads you to a first option and lets you navigate through the choices. Personally, I find this configuration very desirable for the following reasons.

To make my point clear, let's take 'Gmail' as an example. When you open Gmail, it never asks you questions like:

- "Do you want to read an email?"
- "Do you want to write an email?"
- "Do you want to see what you have sent?"

Instead, it leads you directly to the "inbox," and from there, you can navigate to "compose" or "sent." The reason behind this approach is that the extra steps might be useful for a few new users initially. However, as they get used to the app, the extra steps become nothing more than a cumbersome process.

The second reason is that user flow is not always a linear path. Users need flexibility to jump around and explore. If the flow is configured in a linear way, such as requiring users to answer specific questions to reach their desired destination, it can become quite annoying.

Lastly, this navigation method might feel somewhat alienating. For instance, if users can easily access the "inbox," "compose," or "sent" boxes with just one click from the navigation options at the top, they may question why they need to answer questions as they did before.

What’s your thought on this?
Does anyone have different opinion or different angle to share?

Comment: Short inbox, compose and sent are easier to read, translate and make a cleaner layout. Many words may seem to be "easier", but harder to read ("do you want to" read - "do you want to" write are 80 percent equal and harder to distinguish.) Sort of DRY -  IMO

Comment: This is a very interesting question to me because it somehows relates to the book I'm writing which deals (in part) with what you're asking. Now, Gmail's UI is straightforward, offering all options with a click, which makes it effective. However, consider Google's APIs: you need a unique secret and pass for each one and a connector. Ideally, this should be a prominent feature. However the process involves searching for help outside Google, taking 4 to 8 steps depending on the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your idea is obvious, but you need to think about the following point

- do Gmail have the best design
- do the user story in Gmail is very cleared
- can an old man use Gmail alone

I think every UI/UX needs to ask the following question before they make the design,
and based on my experience Gmail is not a perfect design for old ages following your question I think here they need a dialog to show them exactly where to go and lead them with example